# KDE plasma shows black screen

Tags: kde, plasma

When I try to use kde plasma it only shows a black screen, but I can access to the logout toolbar via Ctrl + Alt + Del. The problem simply occurred after a normal start.

My system:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x86_64
Host: 20H5006TGE ThinkPad E570
Kernel: 5.4.0-56-generic 
CPU: Intel i5-7200U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 
Memory: 6844MiB / 15916MiB
```

Is there any way to fix that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1297656/edit) your question to mention which OS, and whether this problem was there since installation.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think there is  enough information to reproduce. When did you start having this issue? What changed?

Comment: @pip1726 thats the weird thing. I shut down my PC normal, after I started the pc the black screen came

Comment: Sorry, I meant "there isn't enough information". So no error messages? Did you made any significant changes before shutting down the machine? Ex. Changed some configurations? Installed some software? Updated some core packages (and got some error message while doing so)?

Comment: @pip1726 Not that I know of, I also reinstalled kde by using:
`sudo apt remove kubuntu-desktop`
`sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` but it dont help

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and have been using 18.04 LTS too long it seems. It happened after I recently ran into some problems with repositories not updating properly or apt update throwing lots of errors. I then uninstalled some un-needed components like the SSTP network manager which interact with Plasma taskbar / applet components like the network manager at the bottom right screen. I then ran update and upgrade and Plasma then crashed anytime when trying to click on any of the taskbar icons like network or screen but not the bottom left application launchers or any icons for open programs.

I found a temporary work around which is running systemsettings5 and changing the desktop theme to something else than Kubuntu or in your case the theme you had running before the last update. Still the problem would reoccur after every update and eventually bring about the black screen you were talking about. On an dual monitor system you can clearly see that it affects the primary screen but not the secondary one. Kwin / Debugging and DrKonqi show that there is a clearly bug with Plasma. Tried various fora and bug workarounds - nothing worked.

When faced with reinstalling the KDE desktop I decided against that in favor of upgrading to the latest LTS 20.04.1 to fix the problem and move ahead with the latests Plasma release - Wayland - let's hope the later is more stable by now (something I will only attest to after a few weeks).